# Не удается запустить проект xamarin vs 15

Tags: android, xamarin

Такая беда : установил я xamarin вместе с vs 15 enterprise, но никак не могу запустить нормально приложение, выходил все время такой эмулятор :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом я обновил в сдк менеджере апи 24,25 (ибо вс напоминал мне об этом), щас сдк менеджер выглядит так :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если выбираю Api Level 19, то запускало эмулятор, который кроме как показа черного экрана ничего не делал (хотя и кнопки ставил и тп), в main.axml все отображалось нормально (кнопки и тп). Если же я выбирал Api Level выше 19, то давала ошибку, чтот связанную с java, я установил java jdk 1.8, теперь возникла ошибка Please select a valid device before running the application.
Это в логе показало

> 1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml 2>Please select a
>   valid device before running the application. 2>------ Развертывание
>   начато: проект: googlemaps, Конфигурация: Debug Any CPU ------
>   2>Ошибка: Отменено
>   ========== Сборка: успешно: 1, с ошибками: 0, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
>   ========== Развертывание: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, пропущено: 0 ==========

Можете подсказать, как мне все же нормально запустить приложение ?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ :
Оказалось, что нужно создать новый девайс под апи 24, создал, теперь уже более 5 мин смотрю на лого андроида 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте эмуляторы идущие с Apache Cordova. Либо строго от Google (к примеру с Android Studio). Либо если для разработки вы используете Windows + VS2015 то эмуляторы от Microsoft. C эмуляторами идущие с Apache Cordova. Постоянно такие проблемы.